# Does Firebase support in command line (CLI) registering new app & downloading configuration files?

Tags: firebase, configuration, automation, cloud, messaging

We have a build script to generate new APP from templates.  Can we also automate the process in Firebase console in the script using CLI?  This is for setting up cloud messaging.

So far all instruction I found is through web UI, as in https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Answer (score 1):

These is not currently features of the Firebase CLI. There also is no API to create apps (or projects) or download configuration files at the moment. Both would be valid feature requests though, so I'd recommend to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).